# We need to deserialize in JS object to Model schema with help of class-transformer

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-transformer

here the issue was when I was using plainToClass() my constructor will throw the error that the constructor parameter is not defined.

Here is my Mongo de query that returns the DeviceOperationsModel[] array. need to make the type check with class-transformer with the helper function of that library.

```
public async find(query: object): Promise<DeviceOperationsModel[]> {
        this.appLoggerService.info(`Finding records on the basis of the following query: ${JSON.stringify(query)}`,
            DeviceOperationsDbService.name);
        return await this.deviceOperationsModel.find(query).lean().exec();
    }
```

Here is the DeviceOperationsModel model class. is have nested class object

```
import { DeviceOperationsRequestModel } from './device-operations-request.model';
import { DeviceOperationsResponseModel } from './device-operations-response.model';

export class DeviceOperationsModel {
    readonly correlationId: string;
    readonly deviceId: string;
    readonly requestType: string;
    readonly request: DeviceOperationsRequestModel;
    readonly response: DeviceOperationsResponseModel;
    readonly createdAt: Date;
    readonly systemName: string;
    status: number;
    statusDescription: string;

    constructor(deviceOperationsData: any, correlationId: string, systemName: string, deviceOperationsResponseData?: any) {
        this.correlationId = correlationId;
        this.systemName = systemName;
        this.deviceId = deviceOperationsData.deviceId;
        this.requestType = deviceOperationsData.requestType;
        this.request = deviceOperationsData;
        this.response = deviceOperationsResponseData;
        this.createdAt = deviceOperationsData.createdAt;
        this.status = deviceOperationsData.status;
        this.statusDescription = deviceOperationsData.statusDescription;
    }
}
```

here is the deviceOperationsData class definition.

```
import { DeviceOperationsDestinationBlobModel } from './device-operations-destination-blob.model';

export class DeviceOperationsRequestModel {
    readonly serviceTimeoutInSeconds: number;
    readonly agentTimeoutInSeconds: number;
    readonly errorOnDisconnection: boolean;
    readonly destinationBlob: DeviceOperationsDestinationBlobModel;
    readonly metadata: object;
    readonly agentRetryCount: number;
    readonly agentRetryIntervalInSeconds: number;
    readonly progressUpdate: boolean;

    constructor(deviceOperation: any) {
        this.serviceTimeoutInSeconds = deviceOperation.serviceTimeoutInSeconds;
        this.agentTimeoutInSeconds = deviceOperation.agentTimeoutInSeconds;
        this.errorOnDisconnection = deviceOperation.errorOnDisconnection;
        this.destinationBlob = deviceOperation.destinationBlob;
        this.metadata = deviceOperation.metadata;
        this.agentRetryCount = deviceOperation.agentRetryCount;
        this.agentRetryIntervalInSeconds = deviceOperation.agentRetryIntervalInSeconds;
        this.progressUpdate = deviceOperation.progressUpdate;
    }
}
```

and so on.

what is the best way to typecast of the Mongo DB data here?

I have tried but with

```
try { 
const result = await this.deviceOperationsModel.find(query).lean().exec(); 
return plainToClass(DeviceOperationsModel, result as object[]); 
} catch (error) { 
console.log(error); 
}
```

but got the correlation, devised, system name, etc are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In the example given in the class-transformer documentation, the class definition has no constructor. See [here](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#what-is-class-transformer).

So, I suggest doing it with no constructor.

However, you seem to be expecting more data in the `DeviceOperationsModel` constructor than just the object. [`plainToClass()`](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#plaintoclass) takes just an object and a class definition.

If you have optional properties that may not appear in the objects, mark them as optional in the class definition.

Also, you do not need to `await` in the `find` function. It returns a Promise, and you are not doing anything with the Promise result in the function. You don't even need to mark it `async` (but maybe you were inspecting it for debugging earlier...).

Comment: I have tried but with 
try {
   const result = await this.deviceOperationsModel.find(query).lean().exec();
   return plainToClass(DeviceOperationsModel, result as object[]);
  } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
  }
but got the correlation, devised, system name, etc are undefined.

Comment: See my edit. Mark them optional in the class definition.